# MongoDB does not full text search in array of strings

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, full-text-search

I try to search in my database and everythig work ok except search on array of strings.
The stored data looks like this:

```
 {
        "_id": "634d8af01f5ed9a5b6669e20",
        "content": "Some example text",
        "heading": "<h1">Domů</h1>",
        "slug": "/home",
        "title": "Home",
        "keyWords": ["one", "two", "three"]
    }
```

This is my Mongoose schema:

```
{
        // _id
        // createdAt
        // updatedAt
        heading: { type: String, required: true }, // <h1>
        title: { type: String, required: true, maxLength: 20 }, // text in menu
        slug: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        coverImgPath: { type: String, required: true },
        content: { type: String, required: true },
        allowUserEditor: { type: Boolean, required: true },
        keyWords: { type: [String] },
    }

MySchema.index({heading: "text", title: "text", content: "text", keyWords: "text"});
```

I try to search like this and content or heading works well, but keyWords does not.

```
db.Article.article.find({
        $text: {
            $search: req.params.query,
            $caseSensitive: false,
            $diacriticSensitive: false
        }
    }).sort({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } }).limit(10).exec();
```

I tried change `.index(keyWords: "text")` to `.index("keyWords":"text")`  and it also does not work.

Comment: Text search only works on string fields and not on arrays